# Override pseudo element ::before if the element has an ID attribute

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, pseudo-element

I added some pseudo elements to my website for all `a` links.

```
#main-content .content .post-inner .entry p a::before {
    content: "\f08e";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

That was working fine, later I realized that it is placing an icon also for Link Anchor as example

```
<a id="anchorname"></a>
```

My question would be, if it is possible to unset the content if a `id` is given to the `href`. The main problem with that is that my anchor ids are never the same.

Comment: A named anchor is not an `a[id]`, but an `a[name]`. A hyperlinked <a> can still have an id attribute. If you actually intend to exclude all <a> elements with an id attribute regardless of whether they are hyperlinks or named anchors, by all means use `:not([id])`. Otherwise, if you intend to apply the pseudo-element to hyperlinks and only hyperlinks, you should use `a[href]`, not `a:not([id])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector combined with [an attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). Then set the **content**'s value of **::before** back to its default value, which is **normal**, in order to make it dissapear (or use **diplay: none**, they would both work in your case).

> The negation CSS pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation taking a simple selector X as an argument. It matches an element that is not represented by the argument. X must not contain another negation selector.

```css
#main-content .content .post-inner .entry p a:not([id])::before {
  content: normal;
}
```

Comment: Oh my.. Thank you so much. I googled arround i never heard that this is possible. Thank you :) that is working.

Answer (score 1):

The `:not()` negation pseudo-class would be my first choice. That's been provided already in other answers. A second option is to create another rule that styles anchor elements with ID attributes:

```
a[id] { ... }
```

You'll just have to note the order of the rules in your code and their specificity.

> [**6.3. Attribute
>   selectors**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors)
>
> **[att]**
>
> *Represents an element with the `att` attribute, whatever the value of the attribute.*

Answer (score 1):

You need to select on the attribute selector `[enterAttributeHere]` in conjunction with the `:not` selector. The basic format of this would hence be

```
a:not[id]
```

A quick demonstration of this can be seen below:

```css
a {
  background: tomato;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}
a:not([id]) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">test</a>
<a href="#" id="one">test</a>
<a href="#">test</a>
<a href="#" id="two">test</a>
<a href="#">test</a>
```

If you need to be even more specific, such as if the id contains/starts with/Ends with/etc a certain value, you could further specify by using<sup>*</sup>

```
[id] {
  /* Attribute exists */
}

[id="foo"] {
  /* Attribute has this exact value */
}

[id*="foo"] {
  /* Attribute value contains this value somewhere in it */
}

[id~="foo"] {
  /* Attribute has this value in a space-separated list somewhere */
}

[id^="foo"] {
  /* Attribute value starts with this */
}

[id=|"foo"] {
  /* Attribute value has this in a dash-separated list somewhere */
}

[id$="foo"] {
  /* Attribute value ends with this */
}
```

<sup>* Sourced from [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you also, one was faster :)